# how to click a html hyperlink from a java file

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am passing an html hyperlink component to a java file

```
<html:a href="google.com" visible="false" id="googlelink">
```

The visibility of this link is set to false. In the java file, when a particular condition is met, I would like to set the onclick event for this link. Meaning, when the condition is met I would like to navigate to "Google Page".

```
TestA.java

if (condition) {
// click the googlelink component and navigate to google page
}
```

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your TestA.java is a servlet, you can do something like this:-

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
```